# Enabling server side settings for on-send feature of OWA

Tags: outlook-web-addins

We cannot launch our examples with with on-send feature for OWA in Office365.

*Enabling the on send feature
By default, on send functionality is disabled. Administrators can enable on send by running Exchange Online PowerShell cmdlets.*

How can we enable this feature for our developer account in Office365 for testing purposes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This describes how to enable on send. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-on-send-addins#enabling-the-on-send-feature

The section "Enabling the on send feature" includes the commands you need to run. Information on Exchange Online Powershell: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj984289(v=exchg.160).aspx